# Cannot execute python command from cmd using single quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I just started the 'official' Python tutorial at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html
and I have a question.

When describing how to execute python commands from the command line, it says the following:

> A second way of starting the interpreter is **python -c command [arg] ...**, which executes the statement(s) in command, analogous to the shell’s -c option. Since Python statements often contain spaces or other characters that are special to the shell, it is usually **advised to quote command in its entirety with single quotes**.

Below are two commands that I ran from cmd on Windows 10 Pro using Python 3.8.3.
Can anyone help explain why enclosing the command in single quotes doesn't seem to work?

```
C:\Users\______>py -c "print('Hello World!')" 

Hello World!

C:\Users\______>py -c 'print("Hello World!")'
(no output returned)
```

I know the tutorial is written for Linux users, just trying to understand why it doesn't appear to work for Windows.

Comment: Because quoting in the Windows CMD interpreter is completely different. If you can't get rid of Windows entirely, maybe install Git Bash if you don't simply want to switch to a Windows-oriented introduction.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/324278/how-to-make-windows-command-prompt-treat-single-quote-as-though-it-is-a-double-q
This might address some of your concerns.

Comment: Thank you both for the links. I'm still new to searching SO/internet and programming. After reading through everything, I installed the Ubuntu developer tools for Windows so I can have the expected experience in the tutorial.